# Why returns the first element of an array only?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$count =0;
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT fwid FROM sbsw WHERE fword = '".$searchText."'");
while ($result2= mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT fsyn FROM wrsyn WHERE fwid = '".$result2[$count]."'");   
$result4= mysql_fetch_array($result3);
print $result4[$count].'<br>';
$count++;
}

mysql_free_result($result1);
mysql_free_result($result3);
```

Comment: I don't see any returning happening. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Also you need to learn how to use `JOIN` s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at how [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) works - for example if you have table structure like

```
id | name | surname | role 

 1    John   Smith    user
 2    Peter  Qeep     user
 3    Mark   Ziii     admin
```

When you execute a query `SELECT * FROM table` and then loop `$result = mysql_fetch_array($query)`, `$result` will always be an array(4) containing

```
[0] => id,
[1] => name,
[2] => surname,
[3] => role
```

Therefore, when you execute the query `$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT fsyn FROM wrsyn WHERE fwid = '".$result2[$count]."'");`, in the first iteration, `$count` will be `0` which is the key for the result returned by the previous query, however in any further iteration it will increase and that will lead to an undefined key. This means that you have to stop using the variable `$count` and just use `$result2[0]` instead.

Also, way better approach to this would be using MySQL `JOIN`, in your example it would be `SELECT w.fsyn FROM sbsw s JOIN wrsyn w ON s.fwid = w.fwid WHERE s.fword = "'.$searchText.'";`

Answer (score 0):

Please, use reasonable variable names and indent properly. You're getting one column from each row as you're only printing out once for each iteration over your rows.

Basically: For each row, print the value of a column.

The $count-variable decided which column, but it obviously didn't make sense at it counts the row you're at.

Something like this should do it: (not tested)

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT fwid FROM sbsw WHERE fword = '".$searchText."'");
while ($result2= mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT fsyn FROM wrsyn WHERE fwid = '".$result2['fwid']."'");   
   $result4= mysql_fetch_row($result3);
   for($x = 0; $x < count($result4); $x++){
       print $result4[$x].'<br>';
   }
}

mysql_free_result($result1);
mysql_free_result($result3);
```

Oh and I changed fetch_array to fetch_row in the inner loop to ease iteration.

Comment: This doesn't solve the main problem - `$result2[$count]`, therefore it will not work.

Comment: Oh my, thanks :) Should work now though, as the closest solution to his approach, even though a join obviously is better

Comment: After the edit it won't work either, you are using mysql_fetch_array which is BY DEFAULT returning a numeric-indexed array, you'd need to use the option `MYSQL_ASSOC` (`mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);`) to get associative array keys :-)

Comment: Don't think so.. From manual: array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )

Comment: Oh, my bad, I always thought the default value was `MYSQL_NUM`.